# Check if DatePicker value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, wpf-controls

I would like to check if the value of a `DatePicker` is null (== no date in the box).

By default the `Text` of my `DatePicker` is set to something like `Select a date`, so I can't use the `Text` property to check.

Comment: DatePicker.SelectedDate == null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The DatePicker class has a property, [SelectedDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx), which enable you to get or set the selected date. If there is none selected, it means its value will be null.

```
if (datePicker.SelectedDate == null)
{
    // Do what you have to do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the default text of the `DatePicker` is `Select a date` but you can use the `Text` property to check by using `Text.Length`. Or check [`SelectedDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
if (datePicker.Text.Length == 0)
{
    //Do your stuff        
}
```

Or:

```
if (datePicker.SelectedDate == null)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to = $('#to');// hopefully you defined this yourself and the options
//I am writing coffeeScript here, below I will add pure JS

if to.datepicker('getDate') == null
  //basically do your stuff here - 
  //using month_day_year_string (m_d_y_s) func to format a date object here and add 6 to the date's year so passed e.g. 2014 gives 2020.
  return to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', getDate(this), to.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', m_d_y_s(getDate(this), 6)))
return// I have this on a call back so I am returning from the call back
```

In pure JS it would simply be

```
var to = $('#to');// hope you defined the options and datepicker
if (to.datepicker('getDate') === null) {
  #do your stuff - I have an example code below as I needed this check in a callback
  return to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', getDate(this), to.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', m_d_y_s(getDate(this), 6)));
 }

return;// if on a call back e.g. onChange or onRender.
```